# Error in command line when executing Stsadm.exe

Tags: stsadm

While installing **MindManager Server** in a SharePoint Server, I had to use

```
Stsadm.exe –o addsolution –filename C:\Mindjet\Mindjet.SharePoint.2010.wsp
```

I get an error in command line.

I have been doing it as administrator.

Trying

```
Stsadm.exe –o addsolution
```

or
    Stsadm.exe

gets the same error message.

Comment: STSADMN is part of SharePoint, and is not 3rd party.

Comment: Sometimes you need to go to the directory of STSADM to run an STSADM command.  The path is : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\#\BIN\ where "#" is the number of the wave of SharePoint. 15 = 2013, 14 = 2010, 12 = 2007.

Comment: It is about a third party product, installation support should be handled through Mindjet.